# Getting, Storing, Setting and Modifying Transform Attributes through PyMel

Tags: python, maya, pymel

I'm working on something that gets and stores the transforms of an object moved by the user and then allows the user to click a button to return to the values set by the user.

So far, I have figured out how to get the attribute, and set it.  However, I can only get and set once.  Is there a way to do this multiple times within the script running once?  Or do I have to keep rerunning the script?  This is a vital question for me get crystal clear.

basically:

```
btn1 = button(label="Get x  Shape", parent = layout, command ='GetPressed()')    
btn2 = button(label="Set x Shape", parent = layout, command ='SetPressed()')
def GetPressed():
    print gx #to see value
    gx = PyNode( 'object').tx.get() #to get the attr
def SetPressed(): 
    PyNode('object').tx.set(gx) #set the attr???
```

I'm not 100% on how to do this correctly, or if I'm going the right way?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more clear on what you're asking for? Are you trying to get and set an attribute for multiple objects?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing the variable `gx`  so `SetPressed()` will  fail if you run it as written(it might work sporadically if you tried executing the `gx = ...` line directly in the listener before running the whole thing -- but it's going to be erratic). You'll need to provide a value in your `SetPressed()` function so the set operation has something to work with.

As an aside, using string names to invoke your button functions isn't a good way to go -- you code will work when executed from the listener but will not work if bundled into a function: when you use a string name for the functions Maya will only find them if they live the the global namespace -- that's where your listener commands go but it's hard to reach from other functions.

Here's a minimal example of how to do this by keeping all of the functions and variables inside another function:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import pymel.core as pm

def example_window():

    # make the UI

    with pm.window(title = 'example') as w:
        with pm.rowLayout(nc =3 ) as cs:
            field = pm.floatFieldGrp(label = 'value', nf=3)
            get_button = pm.button('get')
            set_button = pm.button('set')

    # define these after the UI is made, so they inherit the names
    # of the UI elements

    def get_command(_):
        sel = pm.ls(sl=True)
        if not sel:
            cmds.warning("nothing selected")
            return
        value = sel[0].t.get() + [0]
        pm.floatFieldGrp(field, e=True, v1= value[0], v2 = value[1], v3 = value[2])


    def set_command(_):
        sel = pm.ls(sl=True)
        if not sel:
            cmds.warning("nothing selected")
            return
        value = pm.floatFieldGrp(field, q=True, v=True)
        sel[0].t.set(value[:3])


    # edit the existing UI to attech the commands.  They'll remember the UI pieces they
    # are connected to 

    pm.button(get_button, e=True, command = get_command)
    pm.button(set_button, e=True, command = set_command)

    w.show()

#open the window
example_window()
```

In general, it's this kind of thing that is the trickiest bit in doing Maya GUI -- you need to make sure that all the functions and handlers etc see each other and can share information. In this example the function shares the info by defining the handlers after the UI exists, so they can inherit the names of the UI pieces and know what to work on.  There are other ways to do this (Classes are the most sophisticated and complex) but this is the minimalist way to do it.  There's a deeper dive on how to do this [here](http://theodox.github.io/tag/gui.html)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'll try this and get back to you later today.